# searching in vim editor

Tags: vim

this is a simple query about the searching in vim editor.

consider that i searched for a string like "str" with

/str

now after this search i wanted to search for "strcat" like

/strcat

but, the point in here is that i dont want to type entire /str again.... just wanted to add the new text to /str. that is when we made the first search we type /str and for the second search i just wanted to type cat for searching the entire /strcat.

can any of you vi guru's tell me if it is possible for us to do some search like this in vi.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides up-arrow to get the previous search, you can also do `/^f` to be able to fully edit many previous searches.  (That's <kbd>/</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).  Put the cursor on the previous search that you want to edit, edit it, and hit return.

Comment: Also (as long as you are not in the middle of recording a macro), `q/` does the same as `/<C-F>` (just like `q:` and `:<C-F>` bring up the “ex” command-line history and editing buffer).

Comment: @Chris  Nice!  I did not know that.

Answer (score 8):

The `/` key begins a search string.  `up arrow` recalls the previous line(s).  Therefore,

`/` `up-arrow` `cat`

will resume your search.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question you asked, but on the off chance that incremental search would better suit your workflow, I thought I would mention it.

If you're only searching *once* and finding out that what you're searching for is not unique enough and you need to add more characters, incremental search will show you that before you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Put the following in your `.vimrc` to enable incremental search:

```
set incsearch
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friends. I know this will help me :). you all have a wonderful time